# passing array to webmethod from jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This is my script:

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
    var arr = [1,2,3];
    var jdata = {name:arr};
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'WebForm1.aspx/call',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(jdata),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (dt) { alert(JSON.parse(dt.d).name[0]);debugger },
            error: function () { alert("failure"); debugger } 

        });
    });
</script>
```

This is asp.net web method:

```
public static String call(int[] name)
{
    return "{\"name\":[1,2]}";
}
```

I get internal server error. Can anyone help me find what's causing this.

Comment: Could you append the actual error to the question. You can't expect people to magically know what caused the error. Possibly the error is caused by something else that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are passing JSON object with **name** as property and your web method accepts **int[]**.

You can just pass **arr** to make things work

```
<script  type="text/javascript">
var arr = [1,2,3];
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'WebForm1.aspx/call',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(arr),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (dt) { alert(JSON.parse(dt.d).name[0]);debugger },
        error: function () { alert("failure"); debugger } 

    });
});
```

Hope it helps!!